# Nginx RegEx to match a directory and file

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm wondering if it's possible to match Wordpress directory and specific file in the same location, so at the moment I've got rule to match only the wp-admin directory:

```
## Restricted Access directory
location ^~ /wp-admin/ {
        auth_basic            "Access Denied!";
        auth_basic_user_file  .users;

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        }
        }
```

I would like to also match the `wp-login.php` file but I can't get to work, I've tried the following:

```
location ^~ /(wp-admin/|wp-login.php) {
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't work because of the way that nginx selects a [`location`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) directive. Blocks using `~` take precedence over those using `^~`, so the `.php` block is being selected for `wp-login.php`. The best approach is probably to catch this inside the `.php` block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    location ~ ^/wp-login\.php$ {
        auth_basic            "Access Denied!";
        auth_basic_user_file  .users;
    }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've actually tried that and for some reason the "wp-admin" directory is also matched by this rule (even when I removed the authentication directives for the "wp-admin" directory)?

Comment: Ahh, I think it's because when I try to access .../wp-admin, Wordpress redirects to .../wp-login.php... and then the Nginx rule is applied. Can you suggest the solution for this?

Comment: @HTF I don't understand what you're trying to achieve? Which rule are you referring to, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Sorry for misleading, basically I would like to limit access to Wordpress "wp-admin" directory and "wp-login.php" file by IP `http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule#allow`. I've configured location block for directory but I'm not sure how to match this login file

Comment: @HTF Add a location block to match `wp-login.php` *inside* the `.php` block, as I've shown in my example. Put your access control rules inside there (in addition to the location block for the `/wp-admin/` directory).

Answer (score 1):

One reading your comments on mgorven's answers, i believe this is what you are trying to achieve.

Add this block before your \.php$ matching block.

```
location ~* ^/wp-admin/$ {
    allow 192.168.0.10;
    deny all;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass your_back_endphp;
}

location ~* ^/wp-login.php$ {
    allow 102.168.0.10;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass your_back_endphp;
}
```

With wp-admin you cannot have fastcgi_split_path_info due to this will break styling and js being served.